# WPF Button content to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, textbox

I'm trying to make a calculator and its my first time coding using anything with a GUI

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 WPF using C# application

How do i get the button content to the calculator textbox (screen) ?

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="one" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
        Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Width="50" Height="41"
        Content="1" Margin="31,350,491,64" Click="button_Click"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

C#:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    screen.Text = screen.Text + b.Text;
}
```

it underlines the Text next to the b.

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Something non quite right? Should it be `void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time to learn about MSDN! Here is the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Button` class. You will notice there is no `Text` property, but there is a `Content` property. You will have to cast to `string` as `Content` is of type `object`.

```
screen.Text = screen.Text + b.Content.ToString();
```

Note that you could simplify this code to:

```
screen.Text += b.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 screen.text=screen.Text +(String)b.Content
```

instead of:

```
b.Text
```

in WPF the text of a button is accessed via
`Button.Content` property